# Как вывести массив из n чисел с помощью for..in и for..of в JS?

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, доделать вот этот код:

```
n = prompt('Введите число');
let myArray = [n];
for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    myArray[i] = i; 
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Я написал заполнение массива, но не понимаю как написать вывод значений массива через операторы `for..in` и `for..of`.

Comment: A вот это `let myArray = [n];` что-что делает?

Comment: Ну по идее да, это массив

Comment: Какой вы результат ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: мне надо вывесть массив из n чисел

Comment: То есть вы указываете число, и таким числом заполняется массив с кол-вом элементов равное этому числу?

Comment: для начала нужно создать массив из n чисел, код этого не делает. Можно и пустой массив создать, и в него добавлять

Comment: А что добавлять в него?

Comment: да, я представил фрагмент как пример, просто не понимаю как его сделать через for - in и for - of

Comment: for - in и for - of перебирает массив/объект. Для начала нужно иметь этот массив и объект. Нужно больше информации.

Comment: у меня у самого мало информации, мне просто дали задачу, сказали выведи массив из n чисел с помощью for, while, do … while, for - in, for - of

Comment: остальные я сделал, но вот эти два не понимаю как

Comment: Примеры из руководства не помогают? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: спасибо, щас попробую ещё раз

Comment: ` n = prompt('Введите число');
var myArray = [n];
for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
 myArray[i] = i; i++;
 for(var i in myArray){
  console.log(myArray[i]);
} `

Comment: возможно как то так?

Comment: @Velk Вот я бы например рад вам помочь, но честно, я не понимаю что именно вы хотите. Скорее всего вы путаете какие-то понятия, поэтому и мы понять не можем. Покажите что именно вы хотите получить на выходе (что должно вывестись в console.log?)

Comment: тут зависит от введеного числа, напривер 5 ,а на выходе 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Внес последнюю правку в вопрос, на основе уточнений из комментариев. Автор, пожалуйста, в будущих вопросах добавляй подробности в вопрос _самостоятельно_ (для редактирования вопроса, надо нажать под ним текстовую кнопку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1301053/edit)"). Добавление информации в вопрос / ее перенос из комментариев - помогает и тебе, и отвечающим.

Comment: хорошо, учьту на будущее

Comment: function* range(start, end) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}
for (i of range(1, 5)) {
    console.log(i); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

переписать этот код через for-in или же for-of невозможно.
Потому что в данном вам цикле вы задаёте массиву значения:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    myArray[i] = i; 
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

А for-in или for-of создан лишь для перебора массивов ,объектов и им подобных.

Чтобы код работал могу сделать только так:

```js
n = prompt('Введите число');
let myArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    myArray[i] = i;  
}
//////// Версия вывода для for-in
for(let key in myArray){
    console.log(myArray[key]);
}
//////// Версия вывода для for-of
for(let value of myArray){
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, до меня уже дошло

Comment: @MakeCheats, Ты все правильно написал в коде. У автора задача вывести массив чисел, в задаче указано какими операторами, но массива не дано. Автор попытался написать заполнение массива, у него это кое-как получилось, но далее он не знает как применить операторы для вывода. Твое решение является логическим продолжением/дополнением его кода.

Comment: @Velk, я верно все изложил в предыдущем комментарии? Если да, и ответ участника тебе помог - отметь ответ принятым, нажав "галочку" слева.

Comment: да, всё верно подмечено